# Queue Dynamic Array

Tags: c, queue

i am studying queue in c and trying to make basic queue program. But couldn't manage to allocate memory for my array. Here is my queue declaration and my createqueue function. After allocating memory space for myQueue, i should allocate for array aswell but i dont know how. Should i just type `myQueue->array =(myQueue)malloc(sizeof(myQueue));` will it work ?

```
struct QueueRecord
{
    int capacity;
    int front;
    int rear;
    int size;
    int *array;
};

typedef struct QueueRecord *Queue;





Queue CreateQueue(int maxElements)
{
    Queue myQueue;
    if (maxElements<MIN_QUEUE_SIZE)
    {
        printf("Queue is too small\n");
        return;
    }
    myQueue = (Queue*)malloc(sizeof(Queue));
    if (myQueue == NULL)
        printf("out of memmory space");
    myQueue->array =(myQueue)malloc(sizeof(myQueue));
    myQueue->capacity=maxElements;
    MakeEmptyQueue(myQueue);
    return myQueue;
    }
```

Comment: This code has a couple problems.  I would reccomend you start by reviewing this: https://www.codesdope.com/blog/article/making-a-queue-using-linked-list-in-c/ . Try to model your code on the examples that are in here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i should allocate for array aswell but i dont know how

because of the line

> ```
> myQueue->capacity=maxElements;
> ```

the logic is to have

```
myQueue->array = malloc(sizeof(int) * maxElements);
```

> Should i just type *myQueue->array =(myQueue)malloc(sizeof(myQueue));* will it work ?

only in case *sizeof(myQueue)* is greater than *sizeof(int) * maxElements*, but you only check *maxElements* not too small, when *maxElements* is enough large the behavior is undefined (typically when *maxElements* is greater than 6 when the size of a pointer is the double of the size of an *int*).

---

Out of that :

- It is a bad idea to have a *typedef* defining a pointer, better to have the pointers explicit in the code to see them
- the first *return;* must be *return NULL;*
- knowing *myQueue* is NULL do not dereference it after, you can directly return NULL after the *printf*
- you check the first *malloc* does not return NULL, do also for the second, typically in the same *if*

For instance :

```
struct QueueRecord
{
    int capacity;
    int front;
    int rear;
    int size;
    int *array;
};

typedef struct QueueRecord Queue;

void MakeEmptyQueue(Queue *);

Queue * CreateQueue(int maxElements)
{
    Queue * myQueue;

    if (maxElements < MIN_QUEUE_SIZE)
    {
      printf("Queue/maxElements is too small\n");
      return NULL;
    }

    if (((myQueue = malloc(sizeof(Queue))) == NULL) ||
        ((myQueue->array = malloc(sizeof(int) * maxElements)) == NULL))
    {
      printf("out of memory space\n");
      free(myQueue); /* to avoid memory leak, no problem if myQueue is NULL */
      return NULL;
    }

    myQueue->capacity = maxElements;
    MakeEmptyQueue(myQueue);

    return myQueue;
}
```